# After a search in a sql database, a file is missing in the database, how to handle this

Tags: php, mysql

Have a problem that I do not know how to solve.

Has a database with a couple of thousand documents pdf, mp4, mp3 etc ..

The search works well until I come across a file that is missing, because something went wrong when uploading, the file name is wrong in the database etc .. simply the file is missing even if it should be in the database.

So when i do a search the result came up but when i click. But i dont get the file and end upp in nowhere.

How can I get a good handle on this. Would like to be able to get a text where it says that the file does not actually exist because something has occurred.

The code

```
<?php while ($row = $sqlanswer->fetch()): ?>
<tr>
<td> <a href="<?php echo "../", ($row['doc_type']),"/",($row['doc_main_folder']),"/",($row['doc_sub_folder']),"/",($row['doc_file_name']); ?>" ><?php echo ($row['doc_name']); ?> </a><br></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['name']); ?><br></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['doc_type']); ?><br></td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear what exactly you're doing
In general it sounds like you'd want to add

```
<?php if file_exists(<path_to_your_file>){ ?>

<tr>
<td> <a href="<?php echo "../", ($row['doc_type']),"/",($row['doc_main_folder']),"/",($row['doc_sub_folder']),"/",($row['doc_file_name']); ?>" ><?php echo ($row['doc_name']); ?> </a><br></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['name']); ?><br></td>
<td><?php echo ($row['doc_type']); ?><br></td>
</tr>
<?php } >
```